# How to start secondary risc-v core in Renode emulator?

Tags: linux, qemu, riscv, smp, renode

I'm using Renode to simulate a risc-v system which have multiple cores, and then run opensbi and Linux kernel on it.
But the secondary core seems can't be brought up in Linux kernel.
Here is the kernel log.

```
17:09:32.6490 [INFO] uart0: [host:    0.23s (+3.43ms)|virt:  42.9ms (+0.51ms)] [    0.005740] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
17:09:32.6522 [INFO] uart0: [host:     0.23s (+3.2ms)|virt:     43.9ms (+1ms)] [    0.006713] CPU1: failed to start, ret = -22
17:09:32.6541 [INFO] uart0: [host:    0.24s (+1.95ms)|virt:   44.1ms (+0.2ms)] [    0.006966] smp: Brought up 1 node, 1 CPU
```

Is there any expert of Renode here can give me some advice?

Here is my resc file to set two cores PC.

```
    sysbus.cpu_0 PC 0x8ff00000
    sysbus.cpu_1 PC 0x8ff00000
```

Comment: Can you share some additional details? The REPL file and the complete RESC? It might be related to interrupts not being connected correctly, one of the cores being halted etc. 

A good test to start with would be to run `sysbus.cpu_1 LogFunctionNames true true` - you will see if there is any code executed on the second cpu at all